# .gitignore ignoring more than I want to?

Tags: git, gitignore

In my gitignore, I have these two lines:

```
Project1/web.config
Project2/web.config
```

However, it is also ignoring `Project1/web.config.debug`, `Project1/web.config.qa`, and etc. How do I specify to allow theres?

Comment: This is not normal. Are you sure you don't have an "upper" .gitignore as well? Or one in `Project{1,2}`?

Comment: This is the parent level gitignore

Comment: What about `.git/info/exclude`? In any case this is not normal at all. Maybe you ignore `*.debug` and `*.qa`?

Comment: I found a lower level gitignore and deleted it and found in my top-level gitignore: `*\Debug`. That shouldn't match, though.

Comment: You are indeed right. When I commented `Project1/web.config` in .gigignore and tried to add `Project1/web.config.debug`, it told me it was ignored by one of my .gitignore files.

Comment: Apparently, `*\Debug` does pick up `Project1/web.config.debug`. I have two lines in my .gitignore file:

`[Dd]ebug/` and `*\Debug`. Is there a difference between / and \, and if so, which should I be using to ignore any folders named Debug and their contents?

Comment: Uh, are you using Windows by any chance? NTFS is case preserving but case insensitive, that may explain it...

Comment: Yup, and thanks for helping! I solved my problem, and learned not to use premade .gitignore files! I just removed at least 50 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to pinpoint why a file is ignored, meaning by which .gitignore file, and with which rule, is to use [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) (git 1.8.4+, 2013-08-23, recently [improved in Git 2.17](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49099060/6309)):

```
git check-ignore -v -- Project1/web.config.debug
```

And if you want to ignore any *folder* Debug, this is enough:

```
Debug/
```

The trailing `/` will make sure it does not match any file, only folders.

That command was not available at the time of the OP, but was soon after.