# git check-ignore */** not listing folders

Tags: git, gitignore

*This question was changed, since the error description was wrong! Thanks to help from @Tim and @Jubobs*

I have entire folders in my .gitignore file, but when I use

```
git check-ignore */**
```

When they are deeper in the folder structure, they are not showing up. Is there a way around this?

example folder structure:

repo:

```
repo/.git
repo/.gitignore
repo/hello/__world/test.txt
```

In .gitignore:

```
**/__world/**
```

When I now call `git check-ignore */**` in the root directory nothing will show up, when I `cd` into the `hello` directory, `hello/__folder/text.txt` shows up!

When I call

```
git check-ignore */**/**
```

I can actually see the file.

**Is there an 'infinite' recursion for this? (So I can find files even in deeper folders)**

Comment: Cannot reproduce; shows `folder/test.txt` for me

Comment: Which shell are you using? Is glob expansion enabled? Try running `set +f`, and then try `git check-ignore */**` again.

Comment: Also, where are you running that command? In `repo/`?

Comment: I'm running the command in repo, on Mac OS X btw.

Comment: @NilsZiehn The OS isn't enough information; I want to know which shell you're using. What does `echo $0` output? What about `set +f`? Did it change anything? Also don't forget to use the `@` syntax, if you want to ping a Stack-Overflow user.

Comment: Hey @Jubobs, sorry for coming back to you so late - I actually found that my problem description was flawed. The issue only happens for deeper folders, I updated the question. Do you know a solution for deeper folders?

Answer (score 0):

> When I now call `git check-ignore */**` in the root directory nothing will show up, when I `cd` into the `hello` directory, `hello/__folder/text.txt` shows up!

Note that before Git 2.17 (Q2 2018, two and a half years later), "`git check-ignore`" with multiple paths got confused when one is a file and the other is a directory, which has been fixed.

See [commit d60771e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d60771e93046e9e11183c6ff1fcafd334f8c0453) (10 Feb 2018) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 796a788](https://github.com/git/git/commit/796a788a1c1a2f6a93763312a840d7ed67a8e32f), 27 Feb 2018)</sup>.

> ### `check-ignore`: fix mix of directories and other file types
>
> In `check_ignore()`, **the first pathspec item determines the `dtype` for any
>   subsequent ones**.
>   That means that a pathspec matching a regular file can prevent following pathspecs from matching directories, which makes no sense.
>
> Fix that by determining the dtype for each pathspec separately,
>   by passing the value `DT_UNKNOWN` to `last_exclude_matching()` each time.

So you will have to check again if the issue persists with Git 2.17.